# Why is color transparent when attempting to draw a colored circle with drawRect?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to draw a simple circle in a UIView. I know I can do it with QuartzCore but I want to use the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]));
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

The codes above don't work when i set the `[UIColor whiteColor]`. When `[UIColor whiteColor]` the view would become transparent..

Why does the view become transparent when color is white? How can I draw a circle that's white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `CGContextSetFillColor` state the following for the 2nd parameter:

> An array of intensity values describing the color to set. The number of array elements must equal the number of components in the current fill color space, plus an additional component for the alpha value.

The `greenColor` is from the RGB color space. But `whiteColor` is not. So you end up passing the wrong number of color components when using `whiteColor`.

A much easier solution is to replace:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]));
```

with:

```
[[UIColor greenColor] set];
```

or:

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
```

Update:

Another option, if you really want to Core Graphics, is:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems because of mismatch of color spaces. The context you're drawing into has an RBGA color space by default, which requires the input of four components (red, blue, green, alpha). But when you create a UIColor with [UIColor whiteColor], this color is created with a Grayscale color space, which gives you only two components (white, alpha). Therefore, inserting values of one color space to a different color space causes unintended consequences.

So you either need to change the colour space of your context with CGContextSetFillColorSpace() to a Grayscale color space...

or you can simply use the easier method CGContextSetFillColorWithColor() which takes in a CGColor of any color space and applies to the context regardless of the CGColor's color space.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```